# Zshell custom theme colors not appearing after a login (VSCode & Ubuntu WSL terminals0

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh

I have installed zsh on Windows 10, using WSL with Ubuntu. On top of it the OhMyZsh is installed, with the powerlevel10k theme (https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k).

The problem is that after I decide to login via vagrant to a Virtual Machine (both within VSCode or Ubuntu WSL in a separate window), all customizations of the theme are gone, there are no colors anymore, neither custom elements... (as depicted by the screnshot)

[image]

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks in advance for the help!

[image]

Comment: The left side of the screenshot is clipped just enough to make it difficult to see your problem.  You don't appear to exit the Vagrant session in that screenshot ...

Comment: Apologies for the delay - a screenshot after exiting the vagrant session has been added.

Comment: I must be missing something - The latest screenshot you posted shows the prompt (lprompt with directory etc., rprompt with time, etc.) with colors that seems to be working correctly both before and after the Vagrant session.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, indeed. That's the issue, once I enter the Vagrant session, all customizations disappear.